# Is there a way to implement overlapping horizontal Bar charts in Apexcharts (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bar-chart, overlapping, apexcharts

I want to implement overlapping horizontal bar charts in Apexcharts. Here is the reference image - [image: Overlapping Bar Chart]

Apexcharts bar chart has an option "stacked" through which I am able to create a stacked bar chart - [image]

Is it possible to create overlapping horizontal bars?

Comment: You can use the stacked bar chart to create the same effect right?

Comment: @Netham I can't hide values in a stacked bar chart compared to a horizontal bar i.e, I want to plot charts sharing same y-axis.